# Add a new line at the end of collection

Tags: java, generics, sorting, hashset

I would like to use unsorted generic collection to store values.

```
Set<Integer> map = new HashSet<Integer>();
map.Add( new Integer( 3 ) );
map.Add( new Integer( 2 ) );
map.Add( new Integer( 4 ) );
map.Add( new Integer( 1 ) );
```

I suppose the elements would be 3,2,4,1.
Then I would like to create an array from this set:

```
Integer[] arr = ( Integer[] )map.toArray( new Integer[map.size()] );
```

And I'm surprised because the elements in *arr* are in different order than I put into map.
The deal is to get an array like this:

```
arr[0] = 3;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 4;
arr[3] = 1;
```

What should I do for this?

Comment: maybe an ArrayList will help you better

Comment: [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html): It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, **it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.** This class permits the null element. Use `java.util.List` / `java.util.ArrayList` instead.

Comment: According to JavaDoc `This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time` That's why they are not in the order you put them

Comment: the question title doesn't seem to match the question at all

Comment: You seem to be confussing "order" and "sort".
`Collection`s are ordered if there is precise control over where in the list each element is inserted.
`Collection`s can be sorted if you can order then using the "Natural Order" of it's elements. See [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to implement "Natural ordening".

Comment: Would you explain why you chose `Set` as the type for your variable?
Usually, to keep an order you would use `List`s. But `List`s allow duplicate elements. In that case you would have to use a `Set`, perhaps with an instantiation of `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashSet` does not guarantee that the order will remain same. If you want to maintain order then use `ArrayList`.

Comment: Or just any class that implements `List` (as `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc).-

Comment: Peter +1, as @zuxqoj wrote in his solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sets are unordered. It is not guaranteed to maintain the order of the elements. You need to use a list if the order you added the elements should remain the same.

```
List<Integer> map = new ArrayList<Integer>();
map.add( new Integer( 3 ) );
map.add( new Integer( 2 ) );
map.add( new Integer( 4 ) );
map.add( new Integer( 1 ) );
```

Comment: Nice explanation of why a `List` is needed, and propper use of its interface.

Answer (score 2):

use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead of HashSet

```
    Set<Integer> map = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    map.add( new Integer( 3 ) );
    map.add( new Integer( 2 ) );
    map.add( new Integer( 4 ) );
    map.add( new Integer( 1 ) );

    Integer[] arr = ( Integer[] )map.toArray( new Integer[map.size()] );

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LinkedHashSet` to preserve the input order:

```
Set<Integer> map = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
```